# Finding the probability of a specific outcome within a combination

Tags: excel, vba, combinations, probability

Let's say I have eight independent games in which there are mutually exclusive outcomes of A, B and C:

```
    A       B       C
1   46.17%  26.40%  27.42%
2   90.43%  7.20%   2.37%
3   69.70%  18.02%  12.28%
4   56.58%  25.73%  17.68%
5   27.77%  26.73%  45.51%
6   41.25%  28.02%  30.73%
7   12.52%  21.59%  65.89%
8   67.27%  21.66%  11.06%
```

Is there a formula where I can find out if all eight games are played, what the probability of exactly three outcome `B`s happen? e.g. BBBAAAAA, BBBAAAAC, BABAAACC, and so on?

Normally I can use a COMBIN formula to find the combinations, however since the combinations are associated with a certain probability, it cannot be used in this case to calculate what I need.

Comment: For a question this theoretical, you might want to ask on the Math exchange.

Answer (score 0):

First, how to calculate the probability  for BBBXXXXX, where X is whichever of A or C (ie. X is not B).
This probability =
0.264 * 0.072 * 0.1802 * (1 - 0.2573) * (1 - 0.2673) * (1 - 0.2802) * (1 - 0.2159) * (1 - 0.2166).
Let's denote that with p(123) = p(B(1)) * p(B(2)) * p(B(3)) * (1 - p(B(4))) * (1 - p(B(5))) * (1 - p(B(6))) * (1 - p(B(7))) * (1 - p(B(8))).

Now find all the ways to choose 3 games out of 8 (there are 56 ways to do it) and calculate the probabilities for those in a similar way. The overall probability you are looking for is the sum of these.

Just to be sure, for example the probability for XXBXXBBX = p(367) = (1 - p(B(1))) * (1 - p(B(2))) * p(B(3)) * (1 - p(B(4))) * (1 - p(B(5))) * p(B(6)) * p(B(7)) * (1 - p(B(8))).

Comment: Hi William, thanks for this. Do you know if there is any way to do this through a formula, function or point me in the direction of creating a macro for this?